# Ошибка "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" во время "Show on Code Map"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-map

Ранее просмотр карты кода работал и проблем не было. Сейчас, если я на любом методе нажму в контекстном меню:  <kbd>Show on Code Map</kbd>, то происходит следующее:

1. По началу все идет хорошо, вверху отображается индикаторная полоска прогресса, я вижу карту кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Но в определенный момент процесса построения карты кода происходит что-то неизвестное и я получаю следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки следующий:

> ib___.Repository.dll: Assembly cannot be
>   loaded:C:\Users______\Documents\ib___\ib___
>   WCF\v5.1\ib___WCF_5.1.01\WCF\ib___.Repository\bin\Debug\ib___.Repository.dll
>   Error: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Перейдя в папку, указанную в пути данной ошибки, я нахожу там эту библиотеку, ошибку по которой я получаю. Проект строится, ошибок нет, все работает, кроме карты кода. Чем вызвана данная ошибка и как решить проблему? Как такового ответа на этот вопрос не удалось найти.

Comment: Ну что-то не то с арифметикой - какая-то расчётная величина вышла за границы диапазона которое может хранить тот тип данных который ими оперирует.

Comment: @Чад, то, что Вы предполагаете и я тоже предполагал, так как натыкался на подобное. Но дело в том, что проект работает, все в порядке и ошибка появляется только в *Code Map*. Есть предположение, как решить? Куда вообще смотреть?

Comment: Если раньше работало, и перестало - то проблема в изменившихся данных. Либо ковырять что падает конкретно в библиотеке при её загрузке.

Comment: @Чад, В какой именно момент перестало работать сказать никто не сможет, так как проект большой, в день может быть до 20 чекинов, так что - это нереально. *Либо ковырять что падает конкретно в библиотеке при её загрузке.* - это каким образом предлагаете сделать?

Comment: Через боль, муки и унижение :-) Разобрать её, отдебажить. Хотя, если это проблема вижака - то напишите им в поддержку, это же их продукт :-)

Comment: @Чад, я вот тоже думаю, что придется ковырять много *овна. Пока писать не буду в поддержку, так как возможно у меня проблема. Спасибо за совет, подожду, пока, может есть еще варианты